# Clone staged files in original repository via git clone?

Tags: git

Seems staged files are also stored in the object tree, is it possible to include such staged files in origin repository via `git clone`?

Comment: Just for clarifications: You want all the files that are in the index to be tracked in the repository as well? Actually doesn't make any sense for me, because the commit is a representation of the staged files for that particular moment in history. Or am I understanding you wrong so be free to correct me.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I  am mostly for backup purpose or share staged changes with others so I'd like that `git clone` can take all staged stuff out in a repository.

Comment: My answer will accomplish this.  Do you also want your local changes to remain staged?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen commit it and reset HEAD looks a good workaround. Doesn't include local changes in work directory is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to make your staged changes available in the remote repository, you could commit the staged changes, push to origin, and then revert back to staging:

```
git commit -m 'Temporarily commit staged files for cloning'
git push origin your_branch
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Now the remote has your staged changes for others to use, but the working branch `your_branch` on your machine is in the same state whence you began.